# Adding popup to the dialling screen in iOS

Tags: ios, swift

[image]

while calling to one number from our app, once it start dialling we should able to show popup on dialer screen.

Comment: Are you making the call with the iPhone app or some other service. If you are using the phone app then you have no control over the UI

Answer (score 0):

IOS gives no control on the dialing screen so this is unachievable.